# Summation simplification question

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

> Simplify $$\sum_{k=0}^{n - 5} 5^k (n - k) = \frac{-n}{4} + \frac{21( 5^{n - 4})}{16} - \frac{5}{16}, \quad n \ge 5$$

Could I have any hint to start from the right side to the left side? I separated it into
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n - 5} 5^k (n) - \sum_{k=0}^{n - 5} 5^k (k)
$$

But $r=5>1$ so I cannot use the geometric formula. If I use the formula, I would get
$\frac{-n}{4} - \frac{5}{16}$. What could I do here? Thanks.

Comment: You can use the geometric formula since there's a finite number of terms and $r\neq 1.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINTS**

Note that $n$ does not depend on $k$, so you can write
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n-5}n \cdot 5^k
 = n \sum_{k=0}^{n-5} 5^k
$$
and the geometric series formula applies straight up.

As for the second sum, note that if we define
$$
f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{n-5} x^k = \frac{1-x^{n-4}}{1-x}
$$
and differentiate term-by-term, you get
$$
f'(x) = \sum_{k=1}^{n-5} k x^{k-1} = \frac{d}{dx} \left[\frac{1-x^{n-4}}{1-x}\right]
$$
which you can compute and evaluate at $x=5$.